# Difficulty generating unique arrays for each parent object

Tags: python, random

I'm making a genetic simulator for a game and when I call my function to populate the array that determines the parents gene's it gives the same output for each parent.

Outputs would generally look like this.
ruby = [G, U, B, N, N, G]
jaune = [G, U, B, N, N, G]

The output I want would be something like this.
ruby = [R, A, N, R, N, B]
jaune = [W, N, W, N, N A]

```
import random
import time

class Parent():
    magic = [None, None, None, None, None, None]


    types = ['B', 'U', 'W', 'R', 'G', 'N', 'A']
    def gen(self):
        for i in range(0, 6):
            self.magic[i] = self.types[random.randint(0, 6)]


    def traits(self):
        print (self.magic)



jaune = Parent()
ruby = Parent()

jaune.gen()
ruby.gen()

jaune.traits()
ruby.traits()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a constructor, and self values. Your `magic` is a global variable.

```
import random
import time

types = ['B', 'U', 'W', 'R', 'G', 'N', 'A']

class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.magic = []
        self.gen()

    def gen(self):
        for i in range(0, 6):
            self.magic.append(types[random.randint(0, 6)])

    def traits(self):
        print (self.magic)


jaune = Parent()
ruby = Parent()

jaune.traits()
ruby.traits()
```

Also, you can generate values inside the `__init__`.

Check

- Setters/Getters
- Local/Global variables
- Use `self` when a value is corresponding to a specific class, and not a static method

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem.

Comment: By the way, the problem was that, your magic variable was global, and when the second object's gen method changed its value, it changed for all the objects.